# I'm trying to implement a TypeScript ENUM into my tailwind design to make a generic component

Tags: typescript, tailwind-css, svelte

For my project I'm trying to implement a typescript ENUM to use in a typewind design.

So I've made different enums in typescripts files and exported these to the class I want to use them in.

i.e.:

```
export enum ButtonHeight {
large_button = "h-12",
medium_button = "h-10",
small_button = "h-8"
}
```

And in my generic button class I've first imported the ButtonHeight from the typescript file

```
import { ButtonHeight } from "../../../Datatypes/Heights";
```

after that I defined ButtonHeightClass and set a standard value

```
export let ButtonHeightClass:ButtonHeight = ButtonHeight.medium_button;
```

Then I made a button component and used the ButtonHeightClass to declare the height of the button instead of using standard tailwind terms.

```
<button class="
          bg-primary-color 
            py-4
            w-full
            {ButtonHeightClass}
            justify-center 
            items-center  
            bg-indigo-600 
            text-base 
            font-bold 
          text-white  
            hover:bg-indigo-700 
            focus:outline-none 
            focus:ring-2 
            focus:ring-indigo-500 
            focus:ring-offset-2 ">
{buttonText}
</button>
```

And for the first 2 values of the enum this works. But as soon as I use the small_button value. It doesn't use that h-8 script I gave it and instead uses the height of the text in the button.

And this is how I declare which value it should use when calling the button

```
import {ButtonHeight} from "./Datatypes/Heights";

let small_button = ButtonHeight.small_button;

<Button ButtonHeightClass={ButtonHeight.small_button} />
```

So I don't know where it goes wrong seeing how the other values do work with it. Its just the last couple values in the enums that are not working. And I'm not getting any errors either. When inspecting the button element it does say it got the h-8 in the class but it just doesn't register or something

So if any one could help me that would be appreciated. If further code is provided I can provide it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: That sounds like a regular CSS issue where the content is somehow overriding the height intended by the class.